# Prevent tag inside template loop from being output more than once?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to create a table which with an `id` cell that should span 3 columns based on the `sessions` array length, right now because the `id` cell is inside the loop it gets output 3 times when I only want it to feature once. Is it possible to set something in the template to do this?

**JS**

```
<table>
    <tbody class="js-output">
        <script type="text/html" id="tmpl">
            <% _.each(sessions, function(session) { %>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="<%- session.length %>"><%- id %></td>
                    <td><%- session %></td>
                    <td><select name="" id=""></select></td>
                </tr>
            <% }) %>
        </script>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/egks4ys1/

Hardcoded layout: https://jsfiddle.net/egks4ys1/1/

Comment: I don't exactly understand the question, but are you looking for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/9fzq1edz/ ?

Comment: Here is a hardcoded example layout of what I need to achieve https://jsfiddle.net/egks4ys1/1/

Comment: Why do I need to do that?

Comment: perhaps something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/68ym07t5/

Comment: how about using `index` and doing `if..else`

Comment: @styler:See if my answer below is useful. I have used the `index` along with `if` construct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a template that processes the first sessions element separately from the rest of its elements.

```
<table>
    <tbody class="js-output">
        <script type="text/html" id="tmpl">          
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="<%- sessions.length %>"><%- id %></td>
                <td><%- _.first(sessions) %></td>
                <td><select name="" id=""></select></td>
            </tr>
            <% _.each(_.rest(sessions), function(session) { %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%- session %></td>
                    <td><select name="" id=""></select></td>
                </tr>
            <% }) %>
        </script>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/egks4ys1/6/

Answer (score 2):

I have made use of `index` and `if` construct like below:

```
<table>
<tbody class="js-output">
    <script type="text/html" id="tmpl">
        <% _.each(sessions, function(session,i) { %>
            <tr>
                <% if(i!=0){ %> 
                <td><%- session %></td>
                <td><select name="" id=""></select></td>    <%}%>

                <% if(i==0){%>  <td  rowspan="<%- sessions.length %>"><%- id %></td>
                <td><%- session %></td>
                <td><select name="" id=""></select></td><%}%>   
            </tr>
        <% }) %>
    </script>
</tbody>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/egks4ys1/14/